# I am trying to add a list item to an ordered list from an input in React , but the first item is getting added twice after the first loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a list item to an ol from an input , but the first li after reloading is getting added twice , why is that ?

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
    export function GroceryAllin() {
        const inputRef = useRef(null)
        const listItems = []
        const [items, setItems] = useState(listItems)
        function removeLastItem() {
            setItems(prevList => prevList.slice(0, prevList.length - 1))
        }
    
        function clearAddUpdateState() {
            listItems.push(inputRef.current.value)
            inputRef.current.value = ""
            setItems(prevList => prevList.concat(listItems))
        }
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <label htmlFor="itemInput">Add a/an : </label>
                <input ref={inputRef} type="text" name="itemInput" id="itemInput" />
                <button onClick={clearAddUpdateState} type="button">Add</button>
                <ol >{items.map(el => <li key={Math.random()}>{el}</li>)}</ol>
                <button onClick={removeLastItem} type="button">Remove last </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the function input from calling twice by using the code snippet.

```
changeShipping(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('clicked');
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, would you please clarify that a bit further , where should I use this snippet ?